# Strange D3D11 Error when creatng shader [SharpDX/MONOGAME]

Tags: direct3d, monogame, vertex-shader, sharpdx, pixel-shader

i'm a true beginner in shader programming and i'm using the monogame framework . I'm trying to follow along the examples in this book

> packtpub 3d graphics with xna game studio 4.0

But i've been hitting a wall for the past 4 days trying to make the prelighting renderer works (chapter 3 if some of you know this book)
https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/advanced-lighting-3d-graphics-xna-game-studio-40

1. The code compiles fine , but any mesh with le prelighting shader applied fails to display
   2.When drilling down the shader in the VS2013 locals , i find this kind of exceptions

---

VertexShader    'this.depthNormalEffect._shaders[0].VertexShader' threw
an exception of type
'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException'   SharpDX.Direct3D11.VertexShader
 {System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException}

Which with DX native debugger tranlates to

D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateVertexShader: Shader must be vs_4_0, vs_4_1, or vs_5_0. Shader version provided: ps_4_0 [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #167: CREATEVERTEXSHADER_INVALIDSHADERTYPE]
D3D11: **BREAK** enabled for the previous message, which was: [ ERROR STATE_CREATION #167: CREATEVERTEXSHADER_INVALIDSHADERTYPE ]
First-chance exception at 0x75FAC41F (KernelBase.dll) in 3dTest.exe: 0x0000087A (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x003DB5D0, 0x003DC328).
D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreatePixelShader: Shader must be ps_4_0, ps_4_1, or ps_5_0. Shader version provided: vs_4_0 [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #193: CREATEPIXELSHADER_INVALIDSHADERTYPE]
D3D11: **BREAK** enabled for the previous message, which was: [ ERROR STATE_CREATION #193: CREATEPIXELSHADER_INVALIDSHADERTYPE ]

The baffling thing being (to me) that the library seems to link the wrong compiled shader function to either the vertex or pixel shader

> D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreatePixelShader: Shader must be ps_4_0,
>   ps_4_1, or ps_5_0. Shader version provided: vs_4_0 [ STATE_CREATION
>   ERROR #193: CREATEPIXELSHADER_INVALIDSHADERTYPE]

---

here is some of the shader code ( the effect spans on three shaders with 2 rendering to render targets so the third can use it for the final pass)

```
float4x4 World;
float4x4 View;
float4x4 Projection;

struct VertexShaderInput
{
    float4 Position : SV_POSITION;
    float3 Normal : NORMAL0;
};

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
    float4 Position : SV_POSITION;
    float2 Depth : TEXCOORD0;
    float3 Normal : TEXCOORD1;
};

VertexShaderOutput VertexShaderFunction(VertexShaderInput input)
{
    VertexShaderOutput output;
    float4x4 viewProjection = mul(View, Projection);
        float4x4 worldViewProjection = mul(World, viewProjection);

        output.Position = mul(input.Position, worldViewProjection);
        output.Normal = mul(input.Normal, World);

        //les composante z et w de Position correspondent a la distance % camera et % plan lointain
        output.Depth.xy = output.Position.zw;

        return output;
}

struct PixelShaderOutput
{
    float4 Normal : COLOR0;
    float4 Depth : COLOR1;
};

PixelShaderOutput PixelShaderFunction(VertexShaderOutput input)
{
    PixelShaderOutput output;

    output.Depth = input.Depth.x / input.Depth.y;
    output.Normal.xyz = (normalize(input.Normal).xyz/ 2) + .5;

    output.Depth.a = 1;
    output.Normal.a = 1;
    return output;
}

technique Technique0
{
    pass Pass0
    {
        VertexShader = compile vs_4_0 VertexShaderFunction();
        PixelShader = compile ps_4_0 PixelShaderFunction();
    }
};
```

Well , searches on google left me dry on this issue which makes me think i'm doing something absolutly stupid wihtout realizing it (shader n00b remember :D) .

Any ideas ??

Comment: Not familiar with monogame, but scanning the code with `[ STATE_CREATION ERROR #193: CREATEPIXELSHADER_INVALIDSHADERTYPE]` in mind, should the line:

 `PixelShaderOutput PixelShaderFunction(VertexShaderOutput input)`

not be:

`PixelShaderOutput PixelShaderFunction(PixelShaderInput input)`

Comment: Nope VertexShaderOutput is a user defined struct which carry data from VS output to PS input so i guess this is good (the book author seems to think alike too ;)  )

Comment: I wish I could be of more assistance, however, I did do a bit of research on your predicament, and it seems like the issue may be related to your D3D device, perhaps this thread may shed some more light on the issue: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/584149-solved-invalid-shader-version-issue/ ...all the best! :D